Journey wait time to be changed
Can wait time of a ongoing journey be changed? I have an ongoing journey that sent an email to a DE. The initial wait time was 2 hours. After 2 hours, I added a contact update and object capture activity. If the users did not engage within the first 2 hours, the rest of the users wait until 2 days and if there's engagement, the contact gets updated followed by the object capture activity. I need to reduce the wait time and have the contact/object update right way. What are my options? Attached image consists of my ongoing journey with the wait duration that i want to change marked.

You cannot change the wait time when the journey is active; you need to create a new version of the journey and change it

You cannot change the wait time of an ongoing journey.
As it's a one-time run, creating a new version won't work either, so this is what I'd suggest:

Stop the current Journey
Create a new Journey, and use as the entry point a DE with the people that did the action that you wanted (if it's related to engagement, you can do this with SQL, exporting the behavioral data as a CSV and importing it back to a DE, or with tools like DESelect).
In the new journey, only add the activities up to the point you missed in the previous one - you could even copy the original journey


My team wants data to be updated every hour for a week. Most of my use-cases go through an engagement split. If the users engage, an object activity is triggered. My entry source is always a DE. I wanted to understand if the wait time is 2 hours, do users that engage after 2 hours still get updated or do they just leave the journey after 2 hours? I have seen the later happening and would love to find a solution to have shorter wait times but continue to have data updated every hour for at least a week.

I tried adding repeat every day option but I see that the contacts that did not engage within the first two hours simply went down the second path to exit.

The Engagement Split is like a picture of the engagement 2 hours after; it won't keep refreshing after the contact went through the journey.
In order to do what you mention, you'd need to have a query in Automation Studio capturing the people that opened the email (using _Open), and have that as the entry point of another journey, where you can add the activities you have after the Engagement Split in the original journey. Does that make sense?
